npm yo installation keeps getting self signed certificate in certificate chain error
I want to install npm install yo for SPFX ENVIRONEMENT SETUP
When I ran: npm install -g yo@4.2.0, kept getting self sign cert chain error
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ Node.js version
ErrorClass [RequestError]: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\id\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\got\index.js:73:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  host: 'ecit-repo.xxx.com',
  hostname: 'ecit-repo.xxx.com',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/artifactory/api/npm/Central-Prod-NPM-Repo/yo'
}
× yo version
ErrorClass [RequestError]: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\id\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\got\index.js:73:21)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN',
  host: 'ecit-repo.xxx.com',
  hostname: 'ecit-repo.xxx.com',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/artifactory/api/npm/Central-Prod-NPM-Repo/yo'
}
√ npm version

I have already set this in .npmrc file. only run them in command line, still  strict-ssl=false ca= NODE_TSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
I ran npm from /users/id/ directory.

try npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm@latest
